# Accessing .NET service with Axis2 java client: SecurityContextToken doesn't contain any sp:IncludeToken attribute

Tags: java, .net, wcf, apache-axis

I've been given a wsdl and have run axis2's bin/wsdl2java.sh to generate a client stub. I then followed the docs to instantiate the stub via

```
    ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ClientRepo, AxisConfig);

    IMSFeedManagerStub feed = new IMSFeedManagerStub(ctx, ServiceUrl);


    ServiceClient sc = feed._getServiceClient();

    sc.engageModule("rampart");

    Options options = sc.getOptions();
    options.setUserName("apache");
    options.setPassword("password");
```

(Obviously the user / password is bogus ..ahem..).

Which .. from what I can work out is ok. The WSDL states there should be a Token like so
        `<sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">`

From what I understand I need to use wsHttpbinding (which should be handled by rampart) and TransportWithMessageCredential, part of which includes getting & passing token(s) on requests (I .. think .. I'm pretty new to WCF in general).

The exception I get however is

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SecurityContextToken doesn't contain any sp:IncludeToken attribute
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.SecureConversationTokenBuilder.build(SecureConversationTokenBuilder.java:39) ~[rampart-policy-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.SecureConversationTokenBuilder.build(SecureConversationTokenBuilder.java:31) ~[rampart-policy-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:124) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(PolicyEngine.java:100) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.SupportingTokensBuilder.build(SupportingTokensBuilder.java:62) ~[rampart-policy-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.apache.ws.secpolicy11.builders.SupportingTokensBuilder.build(SupportingTokensBuilder.java:39) ~[rampart-policy-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:138) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:117) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:224) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getAllOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:184) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:217) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getExactlyOneOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:180) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:215) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:174) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:124) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(PolicyEngine.java:111) ~[neethi-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]

Comment: Can you please share your code to use WCF service with wsHttpBinding in Java Client ? I am using Axis2 and facing issue like Security token validation and Binding mismatch. I think Axis2 doesn't allow interop between wcf with wsHttpBinding and Java client.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the answer to this: as it turns out, chunks of the WSDL are saved as xml strings in the code generated by wsdl2java.sh.

These are then re-parsed at execution time (from what I can work out) and get passed in as Policy objects to something further down. The problem is that the 'sp:IncludeToken' attribute doesn't make it into this canned string from the WSDL (or didn't in my case), so when it's parsed (again) the property isn't found.

My hacky solution was to re-add the missing attr to the strings with a quick sed / find+replace. Seems to get further along now. It's still breaking, but on something completely different :P